# Why my Storyboard run when I move my cursor from an element to another?

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I build a small control with a panel of two buttons. When I hover the control I want to show the panel and hide it when I leave. Everything works great, but I have one bug. When I move the cursor from the `TextBlock` to the `Image` my Storyboard run again. I dont understand why because both of them are inside the control. I try to add a `Border` to wrap the control, but it didnt work.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Show">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="QuickPanel">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="18"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Hide">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="QuickPanel">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="18"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Show}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Hide}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Border Width="144" Height="36" ClipToBounds="True" BorderThickness="0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="http://www.streamplay.fr/thumb/fanart/3000/3000/1321396.jpg"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"
           Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="34" Width="34"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="DemiBold">Sample Title</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="QuickPanel" Grid.Column="1" Width="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="18"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Button x:Name="button" Height="18" Content="p" IsDefault="True" />
            <Button x:Name="button1" Height="18" Content="k" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Any idea how to change this ?

Comment: Set `Background Property` of `Border` to `Transparent`.. It will solve your problem..

Comment: @AmolBavannavar Set `Background Property` works. Do you know why ? (Add a proper answer and I valid it)

Comment: this question is duplicated.. Check answer on link given in above comment...

Comment: Should I close this question ?

Comment: Yes.. and mark my comment...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a background to your Border element UI:

Border **Background="Transparent"** ...

If you don't set the background, the space between image and textblock is your parent window.